# How could political rivals use the information below to conspire against 2 top members of a dictators inner circle?

Tags: politics, government, relationships

In society being gay is punishable by death. In my country the minister of foreign relations is gay and tries his best to hide it. The evil dictator finds out but he doesn't care he wants to support his friend. The minister is in a secret relationship with the leader of a neighbouring country and they are both terrified their enemies will use this against them.

The head of the navy's wife dies. After his wife's death the dictator is supporting him as best he can. The head of the navy begins to suffer from depression and anxiety and he work declines dramatically.

Comment: Blackmail, of course.  "Do what we tell you to do, or we'll expose you as the buggering pervert [remember, being gay is illegal in that culture] that you are."

Comment: This is the third of three "dictator" questions and none of them are well formed.  An evil dictator wants to be supportive of a friend over an issue that carries the death penalty?  The evil dictator is supporting a widow?  How evil can he be? And what does the second paragraph even have to do with the question?  I'm turining over a new leaf, so I won't vote to close, but I'm downvoting as this question is poorly written.  I mean, forget political rivals.  Beware the paparazzi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, well, there is much to work with here:

the Navy's head can be persuaded his wife's death was somehow a plot, a murder or something, and create false leads that frame the dictator as responsible for her death somehow.

the Navy's head can be played by an inserted agent that would make sure to subtly feed his depression to the point of insanity or suicide. This can be achieved by planting subtle reminders of his wife all around him, or planting forged personal documents or evidence that would create an impression the wife was miserable in the marriage, didn't love him or betrayed him before her death, or that he was somehow responsible for her death. (It all depends how she died)

the minister of FA can be exposed, of course, which would create scandal. it can even be used to discredit him while other allegations would be planted that create the impression that the demonized FA minister is conspiring against the country with his lover who is a leader of neighboring country. The neighboring country can be accused of secretly planning to overtake the dictator's country and he can even be blamed to be part of the conspiracy, planning to sell his people.

The minister of FA can be extorted quietly, since he's so afraid, he can be made to betray the dictator by giving information about him, or sabotage or even assassination.

These are just some options off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

1. Out the foreign minister to various foreign powers he deals with.  If they share the antigay prejudice it will make it difficult for him to perform his role and he may need to be replaced.  If he is competent and trusted, the dictator who supports him will move him to a different position of power.  The ex-foreign minister will proceed to track down the enemies working against him now that they have given themselves away.

I am skeptical that antigay prejudice could be used to displace a minister who had favor with the dictator.  Anti gay policies are one form of "anti-other" policies that establishment uses to consolidate power by rallying the populace against the Other.  Persons in power and in favor are generally not subject to persecution with these rules.  If they fall out of favor then the rules will be used to justify their fall.

2. This one is easier.  Stir up some sort of trouble which the Navy head fails to deal with, because he is sad.  A lesser general or colonel (a confederate of the opposition and alerted in advance to the upcoming trouble) takes charge and deals with the trouble.  The dictator is fond of the Navy head but cannot risk military humiliations and so the Navy head is gently relegated to a position of lesser authority or a figurehead position and the colonel is made official head.